# Scrape, upload and notify

Tags: web-scraping

I am making an app which sends a notifications to users as soon as a new item is available on an external website

Currently this process is Manual, where I check the update myself and send out a notification. I then update my website to show the new item.

I am trying to use a web scraper to run on my website to extract the information and display it in the app but even that is run manually.

Are there any tools that I can use to automate this process?

So something that will:

1. check the external website for updates, periodically.
2. Get the change and update my website (WordPress)
3. Send out a notification to users

Answer (score 1):

I have automated something similar (excluding the WordPress part). 
It was also an automation for monitoring a website for new items (apartments for rent): when a new apartment was available - the automation would send me notification on my mobile.

**As an automation tool, I used Easybots Studio** (https://easybots.net) - simple, free, had all the functionality I needed out of the box and I could write my own 'bots'.

#### 1. HTML Monitoring

In a nutshell, the automation solution looks something like:

- On 15 minutes Elapsed

  - [HTML Bot] Get HTML of the page

    - [HTML Bot] GetAllBySelector(".someHtmlElementClass") (get all html elements in the list of apartments)

      - foreach new listing

        - Pushbullet Bot.Send Notification on my mobile

[Click to see picture from the actual implementation in Easybots Studio](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hua08.png)

The automation is based on the their [blog entry](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.easybots-community.com%2Fvardarski-pastuvi%2F) ("[monitoring a web site for fast-selling theater tickets](https://translate.google.com/translate?sl=auto&tl=en&u=https%3A%2F%2Fblog.easybots-community.com%2Fvardarski-pastuvi%2F)"), which might be helpful here as well.

So, if you go that path, you will need to explore the HTML of your external website, and see how are the items listed. That is needed for the HTML bot can get all items either by 'SelectAllByXPath' or by 'GetAllBySelector'.

#### 2. WordPress Automation

As for automating the WordPress part - I can't find bot doing that on their web site, nut you can develop your own app (WordPress has REST API possibility), or even maybe contact the easybots support to see if they have such bot in pipeline.

If you are a .Net dev - here is a starting point to using WordPress Rest APIs: https://dev.to/yeisonpx/connecting-to-wordpress-using-c-5688

#### 3. Sending Notificatons

In Easybots, there are Email bots that you can use to send emails, but also some mobile notifications bots (pushbullet, pushover, ..). 
In the question it is not specified what kind of notification is needed, but this should be easy with Easybots.

Other tools out there: WinAutomation, Automation Anywhere, UiPath..